# Flutter: Wrap does not wrap the combination of an icon and a long text in Row

Tags: flutter

I am trying to wrap a combination of an icon and long text. However, since the Wrap does not work in Row.

Here is the code

```
Row(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
          child: Wrap(
            children: <Widget>[
              Icon(Icons.alarm),
              Text('60 Minutes df dfg dfg dg dfg dfg dfg'),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        Flexible(
          child: Wrap(
            children: <Widget>[
              Icon(Icons.shop),
              Text('Lorem ipsumssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss'),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: Wrap(
            children: <Widget>[
              Icon(Icons.attach_money),
              Text('Very expensive'),
            ],
          ),
        )
      ],
    )
```

and here is the screenshot

[image]

I expect the text follows the icon and will wrap if it's too long. However, the example shows the text is in a different line.

Is there anything I can do? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your full requirements, but you may consider using ListTile widget instead of your Wrap widget with 2 children. In ListTile you can set `title` (your text) and `leading` (your icon) properties.

An additional benefit is that the entire ListTile can react to a user tap.

This is an example of a ListTile where long text wraps:

[image]

Comment: Hi @Andrei, I basically want to have a text and an icon in the same line if there is enough space.  If there is not enough space, the text should wrap but the icon is still in the beginning of the text.

Comment: If you want the text to wrap under the icon, there is no widget for that, because it does not look good. I don't think any of the main design frameworks (Google's, Apple's, etc.) allow that. If you really want that effect, you may need to use icons as text characters, instead of a separate widget.